# Convert the class of one dataframe based on another dataframe classes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames , which I am trying to compare using <assert_frame_equal> . The comparison is failing over few columns which have timestamp values.The value seems to be same :

```
     DF1     TIME    1970-01-01 02:00:00
             Name: 4, dtype: object
             ----
     DF2     TIME    1970-01-01 02:00:00
             Name: 4, dtype: object
```

I checked the class of this column :

```
    DF1  :    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
        ---
    DF2:      <class 'str'>
```

Error Message from using assert_frame_equal:

DataFrame Expected type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, found <class                         'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> instead

Can somebody please help , how can I make the classes of two dataframes same. My end goal is just to verify data , (no data types/classes etc). I can't give column name specifically as I have to use this function for multiple data frames , where column names for Date values vary.

Comment: you can convert the whole dataframe to strings `df1.astype(str)` and  `df2.astype(str)` and then compare

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid dataframe class comparison by turning this flag off : check_frame_type

for more info check this out:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html